# Non-negotiable laws in physics

Tags: foundations, laws-of-physics

Are there laws (axioms / principles / equations / inequalities) in physics that cannot be violated, no matter how slightly, by hand without leading to absurdities (singularities, inconsistencies)?

Comment: This appears to be a list-based question which is generally considered as off-topic as being *too broad*.

Comment: What is a "negotiable" law, really? I mean, apart from misuses /shorthand uses  of the term law, such as the second law of thermodynamics, surely it is either  a law or it is not. I appreciate your caveat about experimental results, but don't anomalies between theory and measurement usually give us a new law?

Comment: @KyleKanos Would it still be too broad if I limit the question to the non-negotiable part only? That should shorten the list a lot.

Comment: @Countto10 Negotiable laws are laws that can be violated slightly within the parts of the parameter space that we have explored so far without destroying the internal consistencies of our theory. But they could potentially be violated significantly outside of the regime that we have explored.

Comment: @Emitabsorb yes, still too broad because you're asking for a list.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this question is really answerable, or at least the question is "everything can be violated to within experimental error" Like, I can even envision some theory where you don't have some notion of causality in the sense of, say, global hyperbolicity, but you recover it in some sort of classical limit.

In fact, I would argue, Newton's insistence on notions like this against Liebniz probably stymied the development of special relativity more than they otherwise would have without the sacred cow of Newton's global reference frame.

Comment: I imagine that certain types of violations could entail results that seem impossible to interpret, e.g. probabilities being negative.